# Dynamic import with "from" and import_module

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm

I'd like to import a parameter files according to a country code stored somewhere.

The first code I wrote worked, but my IDE (PyCharm) can not being aware of parameters imported with an exec function (which is normal...):

`exec("from myapp.{}.parameters import *".format(get_territory_key())) # Works but is not PyCharm-friendly`

That's why I tried something based on import_module like:

    `params = import_module("myapp.{}.parameters".format(get_territory_key()))
    from params import *`

However, I got a "No module named params" error.
Yet, params is a module. If I evaluate it in a pdb shell, I got:

`ipdb> params
<module 'padamapp.hds.parameters' from '/vagrant/myproject/myapp/hds/parameters.pyc'>`

How could I make this dynamic import work?
Thanks.